# R Replace special value of one column with value of another column

Tags: r, replace

I know that's probably a common question but I can't find a nice way to apply the codes to my problem:

I have a dataset with two colour columns and I want to replace the "unknown" of the colour column with the corresponding value in colour.y. Sometimes the colour and colour.y columns doesn't match but I still want to keep the value of colour and just replace the unknown.

Here the example:

```
   id  colour colour.y
1   1 unknown      red
2   2    blue     blue
3   2    blue     blue
4   3     red      red
5   4     red      red
6   4 unknown      red
7   4    blue     blue
8   5   green    green
9   5   green    green
10  5 unknown    green
11  6     red      red
12  6    blue     blue
13  6 unknown    green
```

And this is the code:

```
id = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6)
colour = c("unknown","blue","blue","red","red","unknown","blue","green","green","unknown","red","blue","unknown")
colour.y = c("red","green","blue","green","red","red","blue","blue","blue","green","red","blue","green")
data = data.frame(cbind(id,colour,colour.y))
data
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`.  Create a logical vector based on the occurrence of 'unknown' in the 'colour' column.  Use that to subset the elements in both 'colour' and 'colour.y' and replace those values in 'colour' with the corresponding elements in 'colour.y'

```
i1 <- data$colour == 'unknown'
data$colour[i1] <- data$colour.y[i1]
```

---

Or a better option would be `data.table`.  After converting to `data.table` (`setDT(data)`), specify the `i` with the logical condition and assign (`:=`) the values of 'colour.y' to 'colour'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[colour == 'unknown', colour := colour.y]
```

NOTE: It is better to have `character` class for columns than `factor` (use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` construction.  If we really need `factor` class, then specify the `levels` to include the levels of 'colour.y' as well before doing the assignment

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(id,colour,colour.y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R

```
data$colour[which(data$colour=="unknown")]<-data$colour.y[which(data$colour=="unknown")]
```